# When i generate metadata for SAML2.0 and configure it at ADFS, its validity is only 3 months

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml-2.0, spring-saml

**SAML configuration file**
public void init() {
this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
}

```
public void shutdown() {
    this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
    this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
}

@Autowired
private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

// Initialization of the velocity engine
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
    return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
}

// XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
@Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
    return new StaticBasicParserPool();
}

@Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
    return new ParserPoolHolder();
}

// Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
}

// SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
// messages
@Bean
public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
    return samlAuthenticationProvider;
}

// Provider of  SAML Context
@Bean
public SAMLContextProviderLB contextProvider() {
    SAMLContextProviderLB samlContextProviderLB = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
    samlContextProviderLB.setScheme(scheme);
    samlContextProviderLB.setServerName(serverName);
    samlContextProviderLB.setContextPath(contextPath);
    return samlContextProviderLB;
}
// Initialization of OpenSAML library
@Bean
public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
    return new SAMLBootstrap();
}

// Logger for SAML messages and events
@Bean
public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
    return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
}

// SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
    WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl webSSOProfileConsumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    webSSOProfileConsumer.setResponseSkew(600);
    webSSOProfileConsumer.setMaxAssertionTime(600);
    return webSSOProfileConsumer;
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 ECP profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
}

@Bean
public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
    return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
}

// Central storage of cryptographic keys
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
            .getResource(keyStoreFilePath);
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put(keyAlias, storePass);
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, keyAlias);
}

@Bean
public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
    WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    return webSSOProfileOptions;
}

// Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
// properties file
@Bean
public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
    SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
    samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
    return samlEntryPoint;
}

// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    extendedMetadata.setSigningAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    extendedMetadata.setDigestMethodAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true);
    extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
    return extendedMetadata;
}

// IDP Discovery Service
@Bean
public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
    SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
    idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/ats/ssoDiscovery");
    return idpDiscovery;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
            this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), metadataUrl);
    httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}

// IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
// is here
// Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
    return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
}

// Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(appBaseUrl);
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId(metaDataEntityId);
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(true);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    return metadataGenerator;
}

// The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
// and presents SP metadata there
@Bean
public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
    return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
}

// Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
            new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/ats/ssoLogin");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}
// Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
@Bean
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
            new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
    failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
    return failureHandler;
}

@Bean
public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
}

// Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}

@Bean
public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
    return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
}

// Bindings
private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
    final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
            new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
    artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
    return artifactResolutionProfile;
}

@Bean
public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
    return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
    return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
}

@Bean
public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
    return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
    return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
}

// Processor
@Bean
public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
    Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
    bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
    bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
    bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
    bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
    bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
    return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
}

/**
 * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
 * @return Filter chain proxy
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Bean
public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
    List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/ats/ssoLogin/**"),
            samlEntryPoint()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
            metadataDisplayFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/ssoDiscovery/**"),
            samlIDPDiscovery()));
    return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
}

/**
 * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
 * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
 * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
 * @throws  Exception
 */
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

/**
 * Defines the web based security configuration.
 * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
 * @throws  Exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
    http
            .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.csrf().disable();
}

/**
 * Sets a custom authentication provider.
 * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
 * @throws  Exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    init();
}

@Override
public void destroy() throws Exception {
    shutdown();
}
```

I am generating Jks file like this

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore talman-dev-key.jks -alias talmandev
> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048

> What is your first and last name? [Unknown]: [www.qtsolv.com](http://www.qtsolv.com)
>
> What is the name of your organizational unit? [Unknown]: Development
>
> what is the name of your organization? [Unknown]: quarks
>
> What is the name of your City or Locality? [Unknown]: noida
>
> What is the name of your State or Province? [Unknown]: UP
>
> What is the two-letter country code for this unit? [Unknown]: IN

Also i have imported token certificate provided ADFS IDP

> keytool -importcert -alias devkeystore -keystore talman-dev-key.jks
> -file adfs-token.cer

After Generating metadata, when it is configured at adfs, its validity is only 3 months. Can anyone have any suggestion what should i do so that my metadata validity increases?

Here is my metadata file for local environment

```
**<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="com_quarks_bccl_talmandev" entityID="com:quarks:bccl:talmandev">
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#com_quarks_bccl_talmandev">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>5VigwMzuqvNICrCnK6ianq1Q1ttKIP8XhRCExuf66r4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>bhgQfNMVFHoFI7PFOmm7Z8qlaWTRcpMS/o9Q4NIO6f3Y6sp6JHqonX33TKX6uMsTJssqFY6/kste3u5BOCZS9lTdqqAZpj7lZJvQxEeXY9eD/GEo3JYEY6X6R+swiKU3PL4WDB2h6NX8v050dSvryniMTvjcgPFOHwVlvHGRa4W0mci4yRnD2V3PS4W3xzSbAc0xICDLbE/m4CyYpnnAs/WQWt6OujKWnoq2abXUbW/qXPlLmRs5ZRWkKkNx7z8ZfJicU1Z40EukYA8g3SbXLN3HBM+swU2DQv5px+03OdPINZYfA9H1nrsjfekrxhEWRVhBFUX1kQVjYQZdoVd+iQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDczCCAlugAwIBAgIEQPMBRDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBqMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UE CBMCVVAxDjAMBgNVBAcTBW5vaWRhMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZxdWFya3MxFDASBgNVBAsTC0RldmVsb3Bt ZW50MRcwFQYDVQQDEw53d3cuZ3Rzb2x2LmNvbTAeFw0yMDA1MDUwNzQ1MzdaFw0yMDA4MDMwNzQ1 MzdaMGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJVUDEOMAwGA1UEBxMFbm9pZGExDzANBgNVBAoT BnF1YXJrczEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFzAVBgNVBAMTDnd3dy5ndHNvbHYuY29tMIIB IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmxjm5uj0d91vKyGGyN8Cwr5VZ1FL+6GVex83 J5ULHfYhvFEb0sT8oEpJnEaS2flPDQotWWlN7eN57EHAu9Vo1CXWVo2FbUeNbmKcxDxbY/w+VKGU BCJYQOuSdXgzI3lLs9rpR/xdNUfBF6/I7zXdFli/yP6c3MZ8kJjTiJ+EnIYXTkZ4JBzApKjjPqzQ ss2MlFVjWCIXa3C46RUQWKT1uBnDcp+byrxrQYxk4oO2Glv7r/vKdRSXNJxkAnVIQSliU/e3YVrE 3ybdBpmoUi79sd1SK4NdwTtmbWpLBXP0Ale8p0jwU1cRBvB+MDvNSXwzv8nChXtixv5SDKKf3iIx PQIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU9PSyv4q+dH2BtYeRfbEePSe9O4swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAD ggEBAIhcVcCgX58tdHisGqcs2Ti1emDi/jkrYdXttjcKHDVxRYNwZHj2z0wxpJmxCw7Qraf2FC6s mKdUZ0TwTPnWb9AVcNXu65pUJd/3bIPaQYQHb7II/aPD2+53FwAGhQdqV9oWQilu81/aqYLcjZ/I OuSU00xX0K/UE957cbFQl9VbnB34lOIuQRJAxX8y/fcl6yQ4V+4Ak1gcDYBnebehjx2JqCaRo4e8 M8ThYM0Jv0Wb6paiA+nN0uhQeapuwRbjUzOV26s8qzx5BFexWmNDAwGNgntXDOVXpQJdgORecnzC 1CdAjlzJ4ORvNM57ZSPZRCz6WXG/PRd5OcxLD9pktjg=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:Extensions>
<idpdisco:DiscoveryResponse xmlns:idpdisco="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Location="https://localcareers.timesgroup.com:8080/saml/login?disco=true" index="0"/>
</md:Extensions>
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDczCCAlugAwIBAgIEQPMBRDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBqMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UE CBMCVVAxDjAMBgNVBAcTBW5vaWRhMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZxdWFya3MxFDASBgNVBAsTC0RldmVsb3Bt ZW50MRcwFQYDVQQDEw53d3cuZ3Rzb2x2LmNvbTAeFw0yMDA1MDUwNzQ1MzdaFw0yMDA4MDMwNzQ1 MzdaMGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJVUDEOMAwGA1UEBxMFbm9pZGExDzANBgNVBAoT BnF1YXJrczEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFzAVBgNVBAMTDnd3dy5ndHNvbHYuY29tMIIB IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmxjm5uj0d91vKyGGyN8Cwr5VZ1FL+6GVex83 J5ULHfYhvFEb0sT8oEpJnEaS2flPDQotWWlN7eN57EHAu9Vo1CXWVo2FbUeNbmKcxDxbY/w+VKGU BCJYQOuSdXgzI3lLs9rpR/xdNUfBF6/I7zXdFli/yP6c3MZ8kJjTiJ+EnIYXTkZ4JBzApKjjPqzQ ss2MlFVjWCIXa3C46RUQWKT1uBnDcp+byrxrQYxk4oO2Glv7r/vKdRSXNJxkAnVIQSliU/e3YVrE 3ybdBpmoUi79sd1SK4NdwTtmbWpLBXP0Ale8p0jwU1cRBvB+MDvNSXwzv8nChXtixv5SDKKf3iIx PQIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU9PSyv4q+dH2BtYeRfbEePSe9O4swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAD ggEBAIhcVcCgX58tdHisGqcs2Ti1emDi/jkrYdXttjcKHDVxRYNwZHj2z0wxpJmxCw7Qraf2FC6s mKdUZ0TwTPnWb9AVcNXu65pUJd/3bIPaQYQHb7II/aPD2+53FwAGhQdqV9oWQilu81/aqYLcjZ/I OuSU00xX0K/UE957cbFQl9VbnB34lOIuQRJAxX8y/fcl6yQ4V+4Ak1gcDYBnebehjx2JqCaRo4e8 M8ThYM0Jv0Wb6paiA+nN0uhQeapuwRbjUzOV26s8qzx5BFexWmNDAwGNgntXDOVXpQJdgORecnzC 1CdAjlzJ4ORvNM57ZSPZRCz6WXG/PRd5OcxLD9pktjg=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDczCCAlugAwIBAgIEQPMBRDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBqMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjELMAkGA1UE CBMCVVAxDjAMBgNVBAcTBW5vaWRhMQ8wDQYDVQQKEwZxdWFya3MxFDASBgNVBAsTC0RldmVsb3Bt ZW50MRcwFQYDVQQDEw53d3cuZ3Rzb2x2LmNvbTAeFw0yMDA1MDUwNzQ1MzdaFw0yMDA4MDMwNzQ1 MzdaMGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklOMQswCQYDVQQIEwJVUDEOMAwGA1UEBxMFbm9pZGExDzANBgNVBAoT BnF1YXJrczEUMBIGA1UECxMLRGV2ZWxvcG1lbnQxFzAVBgNVBAMTDnd3dy5ndHNvbHYuY29tMIIB IjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmxjm5uj0d91vKyGGyN8Cwr5VZ1FL+6GVex83 J5ULHfYhvFEb0sT8oEpJnEaS2flPDQotWWlN7eN57EHAu9Vo1CXWVo2FbUeNbmKcxDxbY/w+VKGU BCJYQOuSdXgzI3lLs9rpR/xdNUfBF6/I7zXdFli/yP6c3MZ8kJjTiJ+EnIYXTkZ4JBzApKjjPqzQ ss2MlFVjWCIXa3C46RUQWKT1uBnDcp+byrxrQYxk4oO2Glv7r/vKdRSXNJxkAnVIQSliU/e3YVrE 3ybdBpmoUi79sd1SK4NdwTtmbWpLBXP0Ale8p0jwU1cRBvB+MDvNSXwzv8nChXtixv5SDKKf3iIx PQIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU9PSyv4q+dH2BtYeRfbEePSe9O4swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAD ggEBAIhcVcCgX58tdHisGqcs2Ti1emDi/jkrYdXttjcKHDVxRYNwZHj2z0wxpJmxCw7Qraf2FC6s mKdUZ0TwTPnWb9AVcNXu65pUJd/3bIPaQYQHb7II/aPD2+53FwAGhQdqV9oWQilu81/aqYLcjZ/I OuSU00xX0K/UE957cbFQl9VbnB34lOIuQRJAxX8y/fcl6yQ4V+4Ak1gcDYBnebehjx2JqCaRo4e8 M8ThYM0Jv0Wb6paiA+nN0uhQeapuwRbjUzOV26s8qzx5BFexWmNDAwGNgntXDOVXpQJdgORecnzC 1CdAjlzJ4ORvNM57ZSPZRCz6WXG/PRd5OcxLD9pktjg=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localcareers.timesgroup.com:8080/saml/SingleLogout"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localcareers.timesgroup.com:8080/saml/SingleLogout"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localcareers.timesgroup.com:8080/saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://localcareers.timesgroup.com:8080/saml/SSO" index="1"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>**
```

[image: Please find the screenshot of images]